# Maximum Extension of a Spring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, spring

> In the given figure:
>   [image: Spring]
>   ${m= 5\ \rm kg}$,
>   ${F = 30\ \rm N}$,
>   ${K = 700\ \rm N/m}$
>
> The surfaces are friction-less. The blocks are initially at rest and the spring is initially in its natural length.  What is the maximum extension in the spring (in metres)?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please have a look at the the homework tag to see how homework questions are handled here. You will not get a detailed solution, but if you could explain, what you problem is to solve this, you'll surely get support.

Comment: The forces are static?

Comment: Sorry, but I did not understand by what you meant by static forces. This is all that was given in the question. This question was posed by a friend and neither of us know what to do with it. I thought that this was the best place to ask for help. Also, I added the homework tag without knowing the rules regarding how it is handled. I'm really sorry.

Comment: Please do not remove the homework tag from homework-like questions.

Comment: Sorry, but as I explained, this, wasn't a homework question. Since I am new to this forum, I don't know the regulations. Please tell me what I should do. Thanks very much!

Comment: Read the [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583). Under the policy, this question is homework-like, no matter whether it is *actual* homework or not (which is why the tag is named homework-and-exercises instead of merely homework). Asking for the solutions to exercises is off-topic here.

Comment: Could you please tell me what to do? In this case, should I delete the question? Thanks again.

Comment: "If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question." Now that is difficult if your edits are removed later, is it not.  @kyle-kanos please clarify.

Comment: @mikuszefski: It seemed to me that your edits (a) were drastic (changing the entire question) (b) not anything that came from BetterWorld (not stated in any comments) and (c) made the two answers irrelevant (asking for energy relations, rather than the ODEs given). When making your edits, please keep things like that in mind (NB: I had originally rejected your edit as well, but 2 others felt it necessary to approve it).

Comment: @KyleKanos I see. Concerning point a) I would say that it still asks for the maximum extension of the spring. With respect to b) I refer to the comments in the answer of Your-Average-MechEng, where it is clear that BetterWorld does not know dot notation and especially not how to handle differential equations. Eventually, I have to confess that you get me with c). I have to say, however, that the requirement that a non-acceptable question can only be reworded if this rewording keeps answers given to that non-acceptable question valid, renders the hole process sort of absurd. Cheers.

Comment: And @KyleKanos just to get it straight. Did you just write in you comment that there was a 2 to 1 vote in favour of my edit, but you decided to roll back anyway. Wow, that's community thinking.

Comment: @mikuszefski: Yes, [you can see it here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/79365). I decided to roll back the edit because you invented a new question for OP after two answers were posted that made those two answers invalid (only the post is shown in the queue, so the reviewers may not have seen the answers to know this).

Comment: @KyleKanos, repeating the same already disproved arguments is a waste of my time. A petty though, could have been modified to become an interesting one. Cheers.

Comment: Sir, please tell me what I should do.

Answer (score 3):

At the instant of maximum extension of the spring both the blocks are moving with same speed. Since the net external force is not zero, we should solve this problem by looking at it from the perspective of center of mass which is accelerating at with an acceleration $a_{cm}=\frac{F^{ext}_{net}}{m+2m} = \frac{2F}{3m}$.

Now since we are solving this problem from the perspective and Non-Inertial frame we need to employ concept of Pseudo force. In the CM frame we see that both blocks are initially at rest but accelerating. Soon they gain speed and again comes to rest in maximum extension state (w.r.t. CM frame).

Pseudo force on 2m mass, $\frac{4F}{3}$ and on m mass, $\frac{2F}{3}$ towards left. Suppose the 2m mass moves through a distance of $x_1$ and the m mass moves through a distance of $x_2$ then the work on the system by all the forces is,

$$(F+\frac{4F}{3}) x_1 + (3F-\frac{2F}{3}) x_2 - \frac{1}{2}kx^2 =\Delta KE=0$$

where $x = x_1 +x_2$

$$x_{max} = \frac{14F}{3k} = 20 cm$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time! Unfortunately the answer is 0.2 metres (the answer was mentioned with the question). Also, K=700N/m (sorry for the typing error). I'm really sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: Hi there, I might just be being silly, but how do you arrive at saying the accelerations of the masses are the same at max extension?

Comment: @YourAverageMechEng you are right. I made a few silly mistakes. I have corrected them now.

Answer (score 3):

For mass $2m$, let $x$ be its displacement to the right from its initial location. For mass $m$, displacement to the right from initial location is $y$. This means the extension of the spring, $e$, equals $y-x$.

So look at the forces acting on each mass, and apply Newton's 2nd Law to get the follow equations:

$$3F - ke = m\ddot y$$
$$ke - F = 2m\ddot x$$

Now, we don't really care about $\ddot y$ or $\ddot x$ individually. Can we find a way to replace them with something useful?

Well, if $e = y - x$, then $\ddot e = \ddot y - \ddot x$. So we can take the two equations above, and turn them into one equation with all the components we need to answer the question.

$$2m\ddot e + 3ke = 7F$$

Now, solve this like any other linear second order differential equation to get $e$ as a function of time, and the rest should be easy!

Comment: It means the second derivative of y, right?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Trying to understand your solution. Could you please tell me what $$\ddot y$$ is?

Comment: Certainly! The dot notation is commonly used to represent a derivative of time. So, $\ddot y$ is the second time derivative of $y$, i.e. $\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2}$, because there are two dots.

Comment: In other words, $\ddot y$ is the acceleration of the block of mass $m$.

Comment: OK, thanks! But how do I solve second order Differential Equations? I haven't even learnt to solve Differential Equations. I just know a bit of Differentiation and Integration.

Comment: Are you expected to be able to do this question without using diff. equations? If so, then an energy solution might be better. As for diff. equations, it would be too long to go over them here, but there's bound to be a good few articles on internet to cover the topic.

Comment: I too had thought of Energy Conversions at first, but then couldn't get anywhere at all. So I thought I'd try Calculus, but that also didn't yield anything I could solve. I'll try to learn how to solve DEs. Could you try something through Energy Conversions? Also thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: Can't say anything about which method is to be followed. Have to go to bed now. Goodnight!

Comment: @BetterWorld you don't have to solve it. You know that at maximum expansion the masses stop and change their direction of movement (not necessarily absolute, but relative). So the second derivative is zero and the the remaining $e_0=e(t=t_\mathrm{turning})$ is your solution. (I get 0.1 m though,...strange)

Comment: Ok I get $0.1\;\mathrm{m}$ as amplitude, so the variation around equilibrium length $L$ is $\pm 0.1\;\mathrm{m}$

Comment: @mikuszefski Almost, but it's actually the first derivative of $e$ that is zero, because that is when relative velocity is zero, but there could still be a non-zero relative acceleration.

Comment: Yes, you are right; I was mislead by the simplicity of the solution.

Comment: I just was wandering. In the center of mass, I have a division $1/3$ ,$2/3$, due to the masses $2m$ ,$m$. This gives me new spring constants of $3k$ and $2k/3 $. Applying $F$ and $3F$ gives me extensions of $F/3k$ and $2F/k$ which sums up to $7F/3k$. So here again I am missing a factor of 2 due to amplitude. Any ideas how to use this to get to the solution without knowing inhomogeneous second order differential equations?

Comment: I'm slightly confused by your method. It doesn't look like you are accounting for the accelerations of either mass? Do you mind explaining the reasoning of your method?

Comment: Thanks for asking; thinking about it, I even get the factor 2, I guess. Let me post this as an answer (allows me to give more details). Please tell me what you think.

Comment: Aha...can't answer as it is on hold...

Comment: My point is the following. the centre of mass should be accelerated with $2F$ and we are looking at the relative motion to this. In this reference frame the point of the spring that is at the centre od mass is at rest. The centre is dividing the length $l$ in $1/3$ and $2/3$. So I divide this into two independent motions. The first one has a 3 times larger $k$ the second $3/2$. Note that the $\omega$'s are the same $\sqrt(k/m)$. I know the system will expand and at $t=0$ is is at rest.

Comment: So concerning any oscillatory motion this is the upper turning point. This is equivalent to the following situation. I have a mass on a spring and lift it by a certain hight, then let it fall, accelerated due to gravity. The only thing I need to do now is, to calculate my new equilibrium length in this frame under the force $F$. Then I know that it will oscillate with this amplitude, i.e. the distance from my turning point to the new equilibrium, hence, the factor $2$.

Comment: One could also think of it as: having a hanging spring without mass at its equilibrium length, carefully putting a mass and then release it with acceleration due to gravity.

Comment: @Your Average MechEng. Sir, I'm really sorry for responding this late. I've been trying to learn how to solve Differential Equations (have only learnt First-Order ODEs though). I tried to solve the Differential Equation and came up with this: $$ e(t) = A sin (\sqrt{210}t) + B cos (\sqrt{210}t) +\dfrac{1}{10}$$ Sir, what should I do next. I am unable to find a specific solution as I do not know the boundary conditions. Please do help.

Comment: @mikuszefski I think I've now got your reasoning, and able to get a solution without any differential equations. Nice one! I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @BetterWorld As for boundary conditions, you do know them. I'll put it into word form: 1) Initial, the spring is unextended. 2) Initially, there is no rate if change of extension (as the two masses are at rest). From those, you can get two small equations, which can be used to solve the arbitrary constants.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I understood:  $$e(0) = 0$$ and $$e'(0) =0$$. Is this correct? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Exactly :) No problems!

Comment: @mikuszefski Actually, on second notice, I realise that's more or less how The Imp answered, using the key point that the acceleration of the c.o.m. is constant. No need for me to reiterate what's been answered.

Comment: I agree that this is the same idea. The overall calculation is a little bit more simple, but also harder to follow, especially due to the fact that both masses oscillate, not only with respect to the c.o.m.